# Unable to fetch value from angular app.factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to share variable among the controller so I am using angular's Factory. I have following code for the same:

```
var app = angular.module('chartApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.factory('UserVerified', function() {
    return {bool: false}; 
});

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
        controller: 'PredictionController'
    })  
});

app.controller('PredictionController', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', function($scope, $http, $interval){

    $scope.hasPermission = UserVerified;

}]);
```

and on HTML i am just using `hasPermission.bool` to set visibility of a `<div>`.

But the issue is angularjs is unable to identify UserVerified defined in "app.factory".

I am getting following error:

```
ReferenceError: UserVerified is not defined
```

I referred following : [Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/angular-share-data-between-controllers)

Only difference I can find is, I am using dependencies which is not used in the example in the above link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to inject your custom service in your controller

```
 app.controller('PredictionController', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval','UserVerified',function($scope,$http,$interval,UserVerified) {

     $scope. hasPermission = UserVerified.bool; //true

  }]);
```

inorder to avoid breaking of your application after minification of code you can also use $inject in angularjs to inject dependecies.

```
 app.controller("PredictionController",PredictionController);

 PredictionController.$inject = [$scope','$http','$interval','UserVerified']//dependencies



 function PredictionController($scope,http,interval,UserVerified){
   $scope. hasPermission = UserVerified.bool; //true
  }
```

**Note: Services names will be renamed after the minification and can indulge in breaking your application**

Comment: Your comment about minification, although correct, is misleading. OP's code is also minification safe, and as per angular team's official documentation, array notation is the recommended approach.

Comment: @AbhishekJain , correct :) , just showed other approach ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this,

```
app.controller('PredictionController', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', 'UserVerified',  function($scope, $http, $interval, UserVerified){

    $scope.hasPermission = UserVerified.bool;

}]);
```

You need to pass the service as a parameter to controller

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject UserVerified into your controller.

```
app.controller('PredictionController', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', 'UserVerified', function($scope, $http, $interval, UserVerified){

    $scope.hasPermission = UserVerifiedvalue.;

}]);
```

Plus, in UserVerified you are returning a key which is a reserved word. It will work but will create unnecessary confusion.

```
app.factory('UserVerified', function() {
    return {value: false}; 
});
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1eYU4LzV2dGI67Zk3FIg?p=preview) is a plunker as a demo.